# To cover a compact surface one needs at least two parametrizations.

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, surfaces

> If $S$ is a compact surface then one needs at least two
>   parametrizations to cover $S$

**My try**

I reason by contradiction. Suppose $X:U \to S$ is a parametrization that covers $S$, so that $X$ is an homeomorphism. The only argument I can think of uses that $U$ is open and $S$ is compact so that these sets can't be isomorphic because a compact set cannot be isomorphic to an open set.

In other to precise this claim I saw [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1495789/an-example-of-a-compact-topological-manifold-which-has-one-cover) where they claim:

> A non-empty open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is never compact.

Perhaps I am being silly, but what is the formal justification of this fact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Hausdorff space, compact imply closed : [How to prove that a compact set in a Hausdorff topological space is closed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83355/how-to-prove-that-a-compact-set-in-a-hausdorff-topological-space-is-closed)

Comment: So, in $\mathbb{R}^n$ a set cannot be open and closed at the same time? Because of connectedness right?

Comment: Javier / That's right.